Lambda RabbitMQ trigger with multiple queues
I have a Lambda function that should be triggered by RabbitMQ.
I'm supposed to have multiple queues, each one of them will trigger the same logic (same lambda_handler function) but with a different YAML file.
As I understand from AWS documentation, Lambda batches the messages from RabbitMQ and handles them together. What I'm not sure about is whether the batch contains messages from
all queues.
If it does, then in one event I'm going to have messages that belong to different functions and are supposed to have a different configuration.
How can I handle it without checking the queue in many places inside my code?
